# Core-plot legend title

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-plot

I am trying to add an overall title to my legend using core plot on my piechart but cannot find anything that seems to support this, has anyone managed to do this through the core plot library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an annotation. You can add it to the legend layer. Use padding on the legend to create some space along the edge to make room for the label.